# long line logs were divided over 2 records in loki

Tags: amazon-eks, grafana-loki, promtail

I installed loki with promtail in EKS cluster with using helm charts. But, long line logs were divided over 2 records. I tried modifying `limits_config` and adjusted `max_chunk_size`, etc. But, It still causes. Is there any way to prevent logs will not be divided for promtail or loki?

It was divided like this

```json
// Log1
{
  "log": {"key1": "value1", "ke"}
}

//Log2
{
  "log": {"y2": "value2"}
}
```